# Как выполнить синхронизацию потоков - C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Добрый вечер!
Получил задание с определенным условием, а именно "разделить операции на потоки и
синхронизацию потоков выполнять с помощью базовых механизмов платформы (без использования Task Parallel Library и concurrent-коллекций)". Как можно это реализовать?
допустим, необходимо разбить работу программы на несколько потоков: первый поток обходит каталоги, ищет файлы, для которых нужно выполнить расчет, и помещает их в очередь. Рабочие потоки извлекают из очереди описания файлов и выполняют для их содержимого расчет хэш-суммы.

Опыта программирования на C# нет, только Java и С++, но человеку надо сделать на C#.

Comment: Синхронизация потоков - очень обширная тема. Пусть человек приведет конкретную проблему, которую он пытается решить.

Comment: Разбить работу программы на несколько потоков: первый поток обходит каталоги, ищет  файлы, для которых нужно выполнить расчет, и помещает их в очередь. Рабочие потоки извлекают из очереди описания файлов и выполняют для их содержимого расчет хэш-суммы.

Comment: @PashaPash, переоткрывай, он дополнил.

Comment: А тот кто вам дал задание, не придёт на ruSO, посмотреть спрашивали ли вы здесь? Раз такие ограничения, могу предположить, что это что-то типа собеседования

Comment: мне всего лишь нужно понять, с помощью каких операторов это реализовать. Остальное все сам напишу.

Comment: Thread+AutoResetEvent+Queue+lock - если в лоб. Или использовать потоки пула. у вас не сильно понятно ограничения.

Comment: Создаёте две нити(Thread), одну коллекцию "Очередь"(Queue), первая нить добавляет элементы в коллекцию, вторая извлекает. Операции добавления и извлечения оборачиваете в lock(obj), где obj объект доступный обоим потокам. Всё задача решена.

Answer (score 1):

Создаёте две нити(Thread), одну коллекцию "Очередь"(Queue), первая нить добавляет элементы в коллекцию, вторая извлекает. Операции добавления и извлечения оборачиваете в lock(obj), где obj объект доступный обоим потокам. Всё задача решена.

Answer (score -1):

В C# Вам доступен класс [`Thread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) (по ссылке есть примеры использования) аналогичный такому же в Java, который в качестве параметра конструктора принимает некий делегат аналогичный `Runnable` в Java.

Есть базовый [официальный пример на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.90).aspx), который в целом очень похож на то, что можно делать с потоками Java.

Советую ещё заглянуть [сюда в главу 15](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/11.7.php), где описаны примеры работы с мьютексами и семафорами. Ну, и если нужно запустить несколько потоков и дождаться, пока все они закончат работу, то для этого есть класс [`Barier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd537615(v=vs.110).aspx)